# Connect to FTP/SFTP in Dolphin or transfer Nautilus Bookmarks

Tags: ftp, dolphin

I am really liking the power of Dolphin and all the KDE tools that go along with using it. What can I do to connect over FTP/SFTP with Dolphin?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On the left hand side of the Dolphin window, click Network. There will be a item for adding a network location like ftp or scp. Dolphin is a great file manager...

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 with Dolphin and from there I can't login to my Ubuntu laptop.  But, I can open a terminal and SSH to it without a problem.  From Dolphin under Network, I see my Laptop name, yet Dolphin won't offer to let me login to it when I either <RightCLICK> or <LeftClick> on the laptop.  I don't see any way at all to transfer files or SFTP using Dolphin.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to choose SSH option, then in protocol field pick SFTP

Answer (score 23):

If you just want a quick connection, you can click the navigation breadcrumbs on above the file list (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and type directly:

```
sftp://{username[:password]}@{domain}/{path}
```

Comment: I tried this using Dolphin on Kubuntu 16.04 and got a Protocol Error.  I'm sure what you wrote is correct, but somehow I must have introduced a syntax error or something else.  BUT THEN I tried typing just this:  SFTP:{username}@{domain} and BINGO -- It worked!!  (a dialog box pops up asking for the password)  I wonder what it was I was typing wrong on the first attempts??

Comment: Just in case this isn't clear, the entire path should look like this: `sftp://username:password@domain/path`, that is, look like a regular SSH URL. The other symbols in the above answer are only to denote placeholders.

Comment: This doesn't work if your username or password has an `@` symbol in it

Comment: does not work:
sftp://username:password@domain/path

Get protocol error and dolphin says it doesn't support opening websites...

Answer (score 20):

SFTP in Dolphin is implemented as **fish**

```
fish://{username[:password]}@{domain:port}/{path}
```

Comment: I tried that using Dolphin equipped with Kubuntu 16.04 and it doesn't work, but I can still open a terminal and SSH to the laptop I'm trying to connect to.  I don't see any way at all to transfer files across either a local or remote network using Dolphin.  Am I doing something wrong, or do I need to use Midnight Commander or Krusader instead of Dolphin?

Comment: sftp:// doesn't work for me for hosts with ProxyCommand in ~/.ssh/config. But fish:// does.Thank you, you saved me from a lot of pain!

Comment: I needed `fish://` to change the port. Apparently specifying the protocol `sftp://` in Dolphin does not allow a port change.

Comment: Current versions (I am using 18.08.0) seem to support alternative ports with `sftp://`. Tested with Debian 10.5.

Answer (score 5):

1. On the left hand side of the Dolphin main window, is a network link
2. Click on the network link
3. There will be a symbol for adding a network folder, double click it and a pop up window will happen.
4. Select ftp option from the list and another new window will pop up.
5. You are now at the **Net Work Information** place. Type a name for your network folder.
6. Next enter your user name.
7. Then enter the server name. (Enter the server I.P address instead)
8. Press the save and connect option.
9. A pop up will appear for password

On the left hand side of the Dolphin main window, is a network link
[image]

Click on the network link 
Then on add network folder.
[image]

Select ftp option from the list and another new window will pop up.
If secure SSL encryption is activated on your server, can use the secure shell option to login instead.
[image]

Use I.P address, not site address, use the number.
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no SFTP option (SFTP is not FTP)

Comment: Thank You, this worked for me in FreeBSD 13.1, now I wonder, how can I use terminal with it passively.

Comment: cPanel has a option, to open one through it, but only it. Its very slow too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPFS

Comment: LocalMountPoint='' ; siteIP='' ; username='' ; password='' ; sudo mkdir "$LocalMountPoint" ; sudo curlftpfs "$siteIP" "$LocalMountPoint" -o user="$username":"$password"; ls ; cd LocalMountPoint; clear; ls

Answer (score 3):

If you want to connect using a key file.

1. create a config file in path **~/.ssh/config**
2. config file may look like this

   Host <any-host-name-of-your-choice> 
        HostName <provided host name, must be the 
   address>
           User <username to login>
        Port <if you have a port, else remove this 
   line> 
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<valid key path>.key
3. Save the file, in Dolphin Address bar type **sftp://<any-host-name-of-your-choice>**
4. this will connect to server using dolphin and private key file.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how exactly Dolphin works, seems like its using [KIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIO) under the hood so:

```
sudo apt install kio-extras
```

Added sftp for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have done it that after a lot of searching. Go to dolphin, right click to add entry, and then type `fish://<ip>` like we do in nautilus.

[image: sample here]